# np.isin() ignores some entries of array

Tags: python, numpy

I want my program to find all positions in time vector (normally a large vector over time simulation) which fit to the experimental time vector (small vector with just some experimental time steps). The problem is, that the `isin()` ignores some of my values:

```
import numpy as np

time_exp = np.linspace(0,2,41)
time = np.arange(0,0.5*3600,20)
print(time_exp*3600)
print(time)
print(time[np.where(np.isin(time,time_exp*3600))])
print(np.isin(time,time_exp*3600))
```

Results:

```
[   0.  180.  360.  540.  720.  900. 1080. 1260. 1440. 1620. 1800. 1980.
 2160. 2340. 2520. 2700. 2880. 3060. 3240. 3420. 3600. 3780. 3960. 4140.
 4320. 4500. 4680. 4860. 5040. 5220. 5400. 5580. 5760. 5940. 6120. 6300.
 6480. 6660. 6840. 7020. 7200.]
[   0.   20.   40.   60.   80.  100.  120.  140.  160.  180.  200.  220.
  240.  260.  280.  300.  320.  340.  360.  380.  400.  420.  440.  460.
  480.  500.  520.  540.  560.  580.  600.  620.  640.  660.  680.  700.
  720.  740.  760.  780.  800.  820.  840.  860.  880.  900.  920.  940.
  960.  980. 1000. 1020. 1040. 1060. 1080. 1100. 1120. 1140. 1160. 1180.
 1200. 1220. 1240. 1260. 1280. 1300. 1320. 1340. 1360. 1380. 1400. 1420.
 1440. 1460. 1480. 1500. 1520. 1540. 1560. 1580. 1600. 1620. 1640. 1660.
 1680. 1700. 1720. 1740. 1760. 1780.]
[   0.  180.  360.  720.  900. 1440. 1620.]
[ True False False False False False False False False  True False False
 False False False False False False  True False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
  True False False False False False False False False  True False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
  True False False False False False False False False  True False False
 False False False False False False]
```

As you can see, the program ignores `540`, `1080` and `1260`. Did i missunderstood `np.isin`()?

Thanks in advance

Pyrokrates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is floating point accuracy: `(time_exp*3600)[3]` is `540.0000000000001`, not `540`. Look at the output of

```
with np.printoptions(floatmode='unique'):
    print(time_exp*3600)
```

which is

```
[   0.               180.               360.
  540.0000000000001  720.               900.
 1080.0000000000002 1260.0000000000002 1440.
 1620.              1800.              1980.0000000000002
 2160.0000000000005 2340.              2520.0000000000005
 2700.              2880.              3060.0000000000005
 3240.              3420.0000000000005 3600.
 3780.              3960.0000000000005 4140.000000000001
 4320.000000000001  4500.              4680.
 4860.              5040.000000000001  5220.000000000001
 5400.              5580.              5760.
 5940.000000000001  6120.000000000001  6300.
 6480.              6660.              6840.000000000001
 7020.000000000001  7200.             ]
```

Rounding or conversion to `int` gives your the expected result: `np.isin(time.astype(int),(time_exp*3600).astype(int))`